# Indian passport holder: transferring through Istanbul SAW airport -two different tickets and with baggage. Do I need a Transit Visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, turkey

Arriving Istanbul SAW airport on an international flight with baggage and then departing in 5-6 hrs by another International airline to another country.  Do I need to go through passport control and immigration to retrieve my baggage from the conveyor belt?  Do I need to procure a Transit Visa for the same?

Comment: Do you have one ticket, or multiple tickets? What is your destination country?

Comment: 2 Tickets -  Destination country is Georgia

Comment: The problem is, you aren’t in transit - you are arriving and then leaving, on separate tickets.  This will complicate matters.

Comment: It is called Transfers....from one airline to another. Is that possible at Istanbul SAW airport, without going through passport control and immigration?

Comment: Not with separate tickets. Not on low cost carriers.

Comment: If it was in a single ticket, you'd be in transit (and yes, SAW has transit - I've flown through there a fair deal), but you're not with separate tickets. So yes, you need a transit visa to board the flight to SAW and to collect your luggage